# Load page then process rows in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, multithreading, loading, html

I have a webpage that is a site monitoring tool for my company. Basically, it pulls a list of 150 IP addresses from a database, and checks if the webpage loads for them. This takes about 15 minutes to load, I'd like it to load the list and go 1 by 1 and update the status with text or an icon.

Here is my Function block, any way to thread this or help me get to what I need to get to?

```
Function SiteMonitorResults(ByVal WebAddress As String)
    Try
        'Code Example

        Dim httpReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(WebAddress), HttpWebRequest)
        httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = False

        Dim httpRes As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(httpReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        ' Close the response.
        httpRes.Close()
        ' Code for NotFound resources goes here.
        If httpRes.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            Return "Online"
        Else
            Return "Offline"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "Unknown"
    End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I would go for something like this, using System.Threading.Tasks and System.Net.Http
( sorry for C# code )

I left out try catch for readability, but they are required, or the code will crash on the first DNS problem (for example)

```
    public string CheckAddresses(List<string> addresses)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        addresses.ForEach(address =>
        {
            var task = new HttpClient().GetAsync(address).ContinueWith(
                res => result.Add(String.Format("{0} : {1}", address, res.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)));
            tasks.Add(task);
        });
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        return string.Join(", ", result.ToArray());
    }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: How can I use HttpClient in a webpage?

Comment: ok, did not see the ajax tag :-)
You can not use HttpClient client side. What you have to do is using some javascript (say with... jQuery;-). For each remote address, the script will perform an ajax request to your server, asking it to act as a proxy to check the remote addres (otherwise you'll have cross-domain problems when trying to access the remote address directly from the client).

Comment: I'm almost thinking about making a desktop app running 24/7 to update the database every 5 minutes with a value. Might just be a better route, that way if 15 people are in the site it isnt overloaded with connection request. Thank you jbl.